# Display User Data From Map String Dynamic Using Provider

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to Display Data on another Page I am Using provider to get the user data and put it to my model like this:

```
 getUserData() async {
User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!;
String value = user.uid;
return usersFirebaseReference.doc(value).snapshots().listen((event) {

  if (event.data() != null) {
    log("$event.data()");
    final Map<String, dynamic> _userData = event.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    userData = UserData.fromMap(_userData);

    userData!.firebaseId;
  } else {
    print('User Data is Empty');
    userData = null;
  }

  notifyListeners();

  print('Update gotten from User Data');
});
```

}
I am getting Nul from the returning data whenever I try to display the data in homepage as such:
userDataCrudService.userData?.store

Please Is there anything I am doing wrong. I am new to flutter and firestore Please. Thank you.

Below is My Model:

```
class UserData {
  bool? admin;
  String? firebaseId;
  String? username;
  String? email;
  String? password;
  String? name;
  String? store;
  String? address;
  String? phone;

  UserData({
    this.admin,
    this.firebaseId,
    this.username,
    this.email,
    this.password,
    this.name,
    this.store,
    this.address,
    this.phone,

  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'admin': admin,
      'firebaseId': firebaseId,
      'username': username,
      'email': email,
      'password': password,
      'name': name,
      'store': store,
      'address': address,
      'phone': phone,

    };
  }

  factory UserData.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return UserData(
      admin: map['admin'],
      firebaseId: map['firebaseId'],
      username: map['username'],
      email: map['email'],
      password: map['password'],
      name: map['name'],
      store: map['store'],
      address: map['address'],
      phone: map['phone'],

    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory UserData.fromJson(String source) =>
      UserData.fromMap(json.decode(source));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it it is a mistake from me, I am trying to get current user id from firestore but it saved with it own document id, I solved it by saving the document id with the user id at signup.